# Minecraft Forge 1.16.5 get world from player

Tags: java, minecraft, minecraft-forge

Sorry, this may be a stupid question, but in version 36.1.35 there is no PlayerEntity#world and no Minecraft.getInstance().world or anything like that. So how do I get the world of a PlayerEntity then?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The field is called `PlayerEntity#level`, it's inherited from `Entity`.